# Can I transit through Serbia with Romanian TRC?

Tags: visas, transit, indian-citizens, serbia

I am trying to transit through Serbia. I have a Romanian TRC and Indian passport.

Comment: Do you have a resident status in Romania? Residents of any EU contry can enter Serbia for 90 days without a visa.

Comment: Does TRC means temporary residence certificate/card?

Comment: Yeah. I was denied entry in denmark for a couple days. And yes TRC is Temp residency in Romanian it is Permis de Sedere. I have this as my wife is Romanian citizen. I have entered Spain a few months ago for a week and back no issues.

Comment: @Graham Denmark is a special place they dont follow Schengen Code anymore.

Comment: On 30 December 2023, the Council unanimously agreed on the accession of Bulgaria and Romania to the Schengen area. Thus, as of 31 March 2024, both Member States will start applying Schengen rules.